# Phonegap. Cannot accessing remote mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, dns, server

I'm doing my first experiments with Phonegap. I would like to build an app that retrieves data from a MySql server, but it seems that the problem is that I'm not able to connect to my dB.

When I build web sites it's easy. I use PHP and the following code:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
```

where `$servername` is `localhost`

But with Phonegap `localhost`won't work of course so I have to use the `hostname` or the `IP address`.

And here's the problem. I have a VPS with a IP and the host name is, suppose, *vps.my-domain.com*. Both won't give me access to the MySql db and I don't understand why.

The following strings report:

**'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'vps.my-domain.com:3306' (20)'**

```
$conn = new mysqli("xxx.yy.kkk.qqq", $username, $password);
$conn = new mysqli("vps.my-domain.com", $username, $password);
```

My code (HTML+Jquery+Ajax+PHP) works fine when I run it on my VPS and I use `localhost` but it fails when I use the `IP address` or the `hostname`.

I also tried with [mySQLjs](http://www.mysqljs.com/):

```
MySql.Execute(
    "http://xxx.yy.kkk.qqq", 
    "username", 
    "password", 
    "phonegap", 
    "select * from test", 
    function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    });
```

but still without success.

The demo code I found at [mySQLjs](http://www.mysqljs.com/) works fine, so I'm pretty sure I'm missing something about my connection.

**How do I access my MySql db using the `IP address` or the `hostname` rather than using `localhost`? Is there a configuration that should be I set on my VPS?**

Comment: Please do not design applications that connect to MySQL directly from random devices out on the internet. This is extremely risky. MySQL is not hardened against attacks and can be easily sabotaged by someone. Access control is also almost entirely impossible as if someone needs write access you can't lock them down to a distinct group of records. You need to use, at the very least, some thin API that your application interacts with. JSON is a very popular choice since it's so light-weight and HTTPS is the most ubiquitous method to connect to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

After many temptatives I worked it out.

By default remote access to the MySQL database server is disabled for security reasons.

1- You need to edit MySQL configuration file and allow access from  origins different than localhost.

```
nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

2- change the line `bind-address`to:

```
bind-address = your_ip_number          i.e. bind-address = xxx.yy.qqq.tt
```

3- restart MySQL:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

4- with PHPMyAdmin create a user which host is your ip address so that it seems as:

```
phonegap@your_ip_number
```

**Below there's the code (HTML+PHP+CONFIG.XML)**

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Fetch MySQL data into Phonegap app</title>

        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="phonegap.js"></script>     <!-- When you build the app with build.phonegap.com remove the phonegap.js file from the package you are going to upload but keep its reference --> 

    </head>
    <body>
        HELLO WORLD!

        <div id="output"></div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function($){          

               var output = $('#output');

               $.ajax({
                   url: 'http://your_domain.com/get.php',     // FULL PATH!
                   dataType: 'jsonp',
                   jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
                   timeout: 3000,
                   success: function(data, status){
                      $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                         var landmark = '<h1>'+item.title+'</h1>'
                         + '<p>'+item.description+'<br>'
                         + item.url+'</p>';

                         output.append(landmark);
                      });
                   },
               error: function(){
                  output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
               }
           });
       });
    </script>
</body>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

   $db_username = 'the_user_you_created';
   $db_password = 'the_password';
   $db_name     = 'the_db_name';
   $db_host     = 'your_ip_number';

   $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
   if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
       die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
   }

   // Run the query and fetch the data. $html contains the result

   // Convert it to JSON and remember to add the 'jsoncallback' string
   echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($html) . ');';

?>
```

**CONFIG.XML** This is the config file for Phonegap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id          = "com.phonegap.example"
    versionCode = "10" 
    version     = "1.0.0" >

    <!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

    <name>Your app</name>

    <description>
        My first MySql connection with Phonegap
    </description>

   <author href="http://www.my_domain.com">
       Its me
   </author>

   <!-- The two following lines make the difference! Important -->
   <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm"/>

   <!-- In my esperience only * worked. Using the IP address (http://xxx.yy.qqq.tt or simply xxx.yy.qqq.tt) did not work -->
   <access origin="*" subdomains="true" />

</widget>
```

ZIP the HTML file, the XML file and JQuery.min.js and upload the package to build.phonegap.com using your account.

Hope I helped someone!