# 'Content-Length' header is not passed to headers

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http-headers

I'm trying to build a Phonegap app which displays a progress indicator while loading JSON data which has been queried from a MySQL db. I did work out the Ajax loading part from a remote server by [my self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909968/phonegap-cannot-accessing-remote-mysql-database), but now I'm not able find the way out on the progress indicator part.

After lot of searching, I'm trying to make work [this script](https://gist.github.com/db/966388#file-jquery-ajax-progress-js). At present the script does not work for me as `lengthComputable` is false.

I read that `lengthComputable` is given by headers which need to be (or can be) set by PHP like this:

```
ob_start();

// Code...

$length = ob_get_length();
header('Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8');    
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Length: '.$length."\r\n");
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes'."\r\n");
```

Using Firebug I noticed that all the headers I set such as `Access-Control…`, `Accept-Ranges` and `Content-Type` are actually set, but `Content-Length` is not.

[image]

Why? How can I set the `Content-Length` header? Will this make the script 'magically' work or am I still groping in the dark to make a progress indicator?

Answer (score 3):

Your Firebug screenshot shows you have `Transfer-Encoding` set to `chunked`. This usually means the content is streamed to the user as it is generated rather than all at once. In this mode, you **cannot** use `Content-Length`. Presumably your server is stripping out the disallowed header.

You might be able to reconfigure your server not to stream the response, but the easiest solution would be to add a different header, like `X-Filesize` and calculate the progress from that. It probably won't work with Phonegap's automatic progress calculation though.

You might be able to find a way of getting `Content-Length` headers on a chunked encoding server. **Don't**. Violating the HTTP standard might work in one particular scenario but will cause all sorts of problems down the line.

Answer (score -1):

This might not be the best anwser but I got a simple solution for you.

Find a gif of loading you like, just for example lets say this one:

http://sierrafire.cr.usgs.gov/images/loading.gif

Take the gif and put it in the div/field you want the data to be loaded in.

For example:

```
<div id="data"><img src='http://sierrafire.cr.usgs.gov/images/loading.gif' alt="loading" /></div>
```

And in the jQuery code you do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get( "/url/you/load/from", function( data ) {
      $("#data").stop().fadeOut(0).fadeIn("10").html(data);
    });
});
```

This will over-write the loader gif and display the data once it finished loading.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I really want to display the real percentage of data while it loads. I would like that the user knows how much it has to wait and at what point the loading process is.